# Can't edit mysql table: Getting odd error that I can't find anything on: #1305 - PROCEDURE db_name.limit_control does not exist

Tags: mysql, procedure, error-code

There are threads about "Procedure does not exist", but I can find nothing about "limit_control". I don't even have any stored procedures.

I can't edit one mysql table (named 'control' - is that where the 'control' in the error is coming from?) because of this error. An example sql command that triggers the error is: `UPDATE`zenbership_test`.`control`SET`currissue`= '336' WHERE`control`.`id`= 1`

I am able to edit other tables in the database. Can anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a trigger on control and does that have a call to limit_control in it?

Comment: Of course you cannot find anything about limit_control because it is specific to your database.

Comment: Thanks, @P.Salmon, yes, there was a trigger on it. I dropped it and now it's all good. Obviously, I knew nothing about triggers, and the fact that the error said "Procedure does not exist" got me looking in all the wrong places.